# How to change a column value, based on a combination of values from two other columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have panel data for 300K individuals (ID's). Each ID has 1 row per year (2013-2016). Based on 'Code', the status of 'Name' is determined (per Year). However, there are still some errors. If one ID in my dataframe has a certain Name in a certain Year, I want to give everybody with the same Code and Year, also that Name for the same Code and Year. In case nobody has a name at Name for a specific Code and Year, then a NA would be sufficient. It is kinda tricky, because ID's can switch with Codes over the years (not within a year)..

For example: For ID #2, the Name for 2014 should change from NA to PIZZA, based on the fact that another ID in the dataframe (here #1) has 'PIZZA' for the same Code and Year. However, ID#3 and ID#4 stay both NA for 2016, because nobody with Code 05/1234 and Year 2016 has a Name in the dataframe.

```
    > str(Poging23)
tibble [16 x 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ID           : num [1:16] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ Date_of_birth: POSIXct[1:16], format: "2000-05-25" "2000-05-25" "2000-05-25" "2000-05-25" ...
 $ Code         : chr [1:16] "01/1234" "01/1234" "01/1234" "01/1234" ...
 $ Year         : num [1:16] 2013 2014 2015 2016 2013 ...
 $ Name         : chr [1:16] "PIZZA" "PIZZA" "NA" "NA" ...

> dput(Poging23)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4), Date_of_birth = structure(c(959212800, 959212800, 959212800, 
959212800, 25315200, 25315200, 25315200, 25315200, 277862400, 
277862400, 277862400, 277862400, 1267574400, 1267574400, 1267574400, 
1267574400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Code = c("01/1234", "01/1234", "01/1234", "01/1234", "01/1234", 
    "01/1234", "01/1234", "01/1234", "01/1234", "01/1234", "05/1234", 
    "05/1234", "05/1234", "05/1234", "05/1234", "05/1234"), Year = c(2013, 
    2014, 2015, 2016, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
    2016, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), Name = c("PIZZA", "PIZZA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "PIZZA", "NA", "NA", "PIZZA", "NA", 
    "NA", "PASTA", "PASTA", "PASTA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Unfortunately, these codes didn't work properly (didn't take changes in code over the years into account): How to change an ID's NA to character value, based on other ID's cell values/characteristics in R?.

Edit: I named NA to "NA" because I made a preview in Excel first.

It's is also okay to change all the Names to 1, and NA's to 0 if that makes it easier.

Hopefully someone can help me/give tips!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution within the `tidyverse` universe can be carried out as following. I divided the procedure in steps so it is more clear and understandable.

First, we create a lookup table that contains, for each combination of `Code` and `Year`, all the values in `Name` that are different from `"NA"`

```
library(tidyverse)

lookup <- Poging23 %>% 
  group_by(Code, Year) %>% 
  group_modify(~unique(.$Name) %>% enframe(name = NULL, value = "Name")) %>% 
  filter(Name != "NA")

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Code, Year [6]
#   Code     Year Name 
#   <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
# 1 01/1234  2013 PIZZA
# 2 01/1234  2014 PIZZA
# 3 01/1234  2015 PIZZA
# 4 05/1234  2013 PASTA
# 5 05/1234  2014 PASTA
# 6 05/1234  2015 PASTA
```

Afterwards, we use a left join between the original dataset and this lookup table

```
Poging23 %>% 
  select(-Name) %>% 
  left_join(lookup, by = c("Code", "Year"))
```

The final output should be as you expect

```
# A tibble: 16 x 5
#       ID Date_of_birth       Code     Year Name 
#    <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>   <dbl> <chr>
#  1     1 2000-05-25 00:00:00 01/1234  2013 PIZZA
#  2     1 2000-05-25 00:00:00 01/1234  2014 PIZZA
#  3     1 2000-05-25 00:00:00 01/1234  2015 PIZZA
#  4     1 2000-05-25 00:00:00 01/1234  2016 NA   
#  5     2 1970-10-21 00:00:00 01/1234  2013 PIZZA
#  6     2 1970-10-21 00:00:00 01/1234  2014 PIZZA
#  7     2 1970-10-21 00:00:00 01/1234  2015 PIZZA
#  8     2 1970-10-21 00:00:00 01/1234  2016 NA   
#  9     3 1978-10-22 00:00:00 01/1234  2013 PIZZA
# 10     3 1978-10-22 00:00:00 01/1234  2014 PIZZA
# 11     3 1978-10-22 00:00:00 05/1234  2015 PASTA
# 12     3 1978-10-22 00:00:00 05/1234  2016 NA   
# 13     4 2010-03-03 00:00:00 05/1234  2013 PASTA
# 14     4 2010-03-03 00:00:00 05/1234  2014 PASTA
# 15     4 2010-03-03 00:00:00 05/1234  2015 PASTA
# 16     4 2010-03-03 00:00:00 05/1234  2016 NA
```

---

If you want to avoid dividing the procedure in smaller steps, just combine the chunks of code as following

```
library(tidyverse)

Poging23 %>% 
  select(-Name) %>% 
  left_join(Poging23 %>% 
              group_by(Code, Year) %>% 
              group_modify(~unique(.$Name) %>% enframe(name = NULL, value = "Name")) %>% 
              filter(Name != "NA"),
            by = c("Code", "Year"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Function aggregate Name by Code and Year will show Names for each pair of factors. For each pair you can see if at least one name exist

```
aggregate(Name ~ Year + Code, dfx, function(x) {x[x != "NA"]})
  Year    Code         Name
1 2013 01/1234        PIZZA
2 2014 01/1234 PIZZA, PIZZA
3 2015 01/1234        PIZZA
4 2016 01/1234             
5 2013 05/1234        PASTA
6 2014 05/1234        PASTA
7 2015 05/1234        PASTA
8 2016 05/1234
```

I will assume that each pair Year, Code must have always the same Name (could be repeated as in line 2) and only need the first

```
uu <- aggregate(Name ~ Year + Code, dfx, function(x) {x[x != "NA"][1]})
> uu
  Year    Code  Name
1 2013 01/1234 PIZZA
2 2014 01/1234 PIZZA
3 2015 01/1234 PIZZA
4 2016 01/1234  <NA>
5 2013 05/1234 PASTA
6 2014 05/1234 PASTA
7 2015 05/1234 PASTA
8 2016 05/1234  <NA>
```

Then for each row of ***uu*** matching rows in dfx, the corresponding Name can be assigned from uu$Name

```
for (i in 1:nrow(uu)) {
  dfx[
     dfx$Name=="NA" 
     & dfx$Code == uu[i, "Code"] 
     & dfx$Year == uu[i, "Year"] , "Name" ] <- uu[i, "Name"]
}
> dfx
   ID Date_of_birth    Code Year  Name
1   1    2000-05-25 01/1234 2013 PIZZA
2   1    2000-05-25 01/1234 2014 PIZZA
3   1    2000-05-25 01/1234 2015 PIZZA
4   1    2000-05-25 01/1234 2016  <NA>
5   2    1970-10-21 01/1234 2013 PIZZA
6   2    1970-10-21 01/1234 2014 PIZZA
7   2    1970-10-21 01/1234 2015 PIZZA
8   2    1970-10-21 01/1234 2016  <NA>
9   3    1978-10-22 01/1234 2013 PIZZA
10  3    1978-10-22 01/1234 2014 PIZZA
11  3    1978-10-22 05/1234 2015 PASTA
12  3    1978-10-22 05/1234 2016  <NA>
13  4    2010-03-03 05/1234 2013 PASTA
14  4    2010-03-03 05/1234 2014 PASTA
15  4    2010-03-03 05/1234 2015 PASTA
16  4    2010-03-03 05/1234 2016  <NA>
```